# Reading a file in and perform another task based on that

Tags: c, file

I'm currently learning File I/O in C. I try to write a string in a text file, and then try reading file to get the string that written in the file so far. And use it to perform other tasks. Writing and reading file are fine, but then I can not do anything with the string.

here is my attempt:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

#define N 100

void fileTest(char str[N], char c) {
    FILE* fp;
    int count = 0;
    
    fp = fopen("assign1.txt", "wt");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("file not found!\n");
        return;
    }
    // writing string to file
    fprintf(fp, "%s", str);
    // reading it back
    fscanf(fp, "%s", str);

    // to ensure every character in str is consistent, lower or upper.
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); ++i) {
        str[i] = tolower((char)str[i]);
    }
    
    // count appearance of `c` in str
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); ++i) {
        if (c == str[i]) {
            count += 1;
        }
    }
    
    printf("character %c appeared %d times", c, count);
    fclose(fp);
}

int main() {
    char str[N], c;
    printf("enter str: ");
    scanf("%s", &str);
    printf("c: ");
    scanf("%c", &c);
    fileTest(str, c);
}
```

Comment: If this is C code, this question doesn't need the C++ tag.

Comment: You should explain what happens when you compile/run this code, and why that's wrong, i.e. what should happen instead, with sample input data, desired output, and current output.

Comment: You're going to have to elaborate on what you mean by "cannot do anything with the string" . For the posted code, and the test input (which should also be part of your question), what is your expected workflow and output result, what is the *actual* workflow and output result, and what is the difference. That information belongs [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67304381/edit). That said, I question the `fscanf(fp, "%s", str);` immediately after the `fwrite` call on the same source file, opened in write-text mode (for some reason). You already have the string, so, ???

Comment: "file not found!\n" is the canonical example of a useless error message.  Give the user an accurate reason for the failure: `fp = fopen("assign1.txt", "w"); if( fp == NULL ){ perror("assign1.txt"); ... }`

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems. First, you open the file like this:

```
fp = fopen("assign1.txt", "wt");
```

This means the file is open for writing. It's NOT open for reading. So your attempt to read it back probably fails.

But it's going to fail twice. You do this:

```
fprintf(fp, "%s", str);
fscanf(fp, "%s", str);
```

So, you have to understand how this works. The file keeps a sort of "current pointer" going. After you write the string, the pointer is set to the end of the file. When you try to read (if you had opened with w+ so the read works), you're still at the wrong place. You need to seek back to the beginning. I think the call looks like:

```
fseek(fp, 0);
```

This puts the current pointer back to the beginning of the file.

So, the changes you need:

```
fp = fopen("assign1.txt", "w+");  // open in read-write mode.

// do the fprintf
fseek(fp, 0);
// do the fscanf
```

I haven't tested it, so I'm not 100% sure this is complete.

Comment: @Joshph Larson yeah you right, I just start learning C File IO and just follow the tutorial and do not pay attention to the file modes. Using fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET) to moving the pointer to the start of the string. Thank you!